Asset not cached
I just installed webot R2023b. I tried to do the first tutorial task that involves importing the e-puck robot. I got an error message that says:
ERROR: Retrieval of PROTO 'E-puck.proto' was unsuccessful, the asset should be cached but it is not.

Please, how do I handle this problem?

You probably don't have an internet connection or there is something like a proxy on the way, so Webots cannot pull the models. Webots pulls the models from GitHub so make sure you can access GitHub from the computer.
